# Get a line with spaces of unknown size

Tags: c++, string, spaces, cin

I want to read a string, the string can contain spaces.

I tried:

```
char* str;
cin >> str; // but I have to allocate a memory by making new
```

so I think about:

```
string str;
cin >> str;
```

but it reads until the first space.

can someone know how can I get it? maybe `getline`?

I can use only the includes of `iostream` and `string`.

Comment: "maybe `getline`"? Yes, `getline`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.

```
string str;
std::getline( cin, str );
```

This will read until a *newline* is detected, not just any whitespace character.